# Broadcasting to Users

Tags: php, telegram-bot

how to use Broadcast message to user Without an error by use in site :

https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, your question header and description is not giving enough clarification.

Comment: Hi Amin, It would be awesome if you can show your progress for ex: a code block or attempts you have made to solve this problem. that way others would understand your problem and will be able to help you faster. have fun!